# FileDialog dúvida c#

Tags: c#

Boas, possuo o seguinte código no meu programa:

**CÓDIGO**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Ficheiro de Configuração (*.cnf)|*.cnf|Ficheiro de Request (*.csr)|*.csr";
        DialogResult resposta = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (resposta == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string arquivo = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            VariaveisGlobais.CNF = arquivo;
            VariaveisGlobais.CSR = label2.Text;
        }

        label2.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button3.Enabled = true;
        textBox3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
```

Como podem ver, quando o FileDialog recebe algo, coloca o button2 e button3 = Enabled.
O que pretendo agora é que se o utilizador escolher um ficheiro .cnf o button2 fica Enabled = true; e o button3 Enabled = false;

E se escolher o ficheiro .csr o inverso.
Podem ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
 button2.Enabled = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) == ".cnf";
 button3.Enabled = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) == ".csr";
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa [`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
switch(Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName))
{
    case ".cnf":
        //...
        break;
    case ".csr":
        //...
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Formato nao suportado");
}
```